# Express.static, Website works fine but "GET http://localhost:5000/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" Appears

Tags: javascript, express, server

I have a problem about `express.static`.

My project is a simple portfolio website with a form to send an email. I followed this tutorial to use nodemailer: [Tutorial Nodemailer Github](https://github.com/victoria-lo/Nodemailer-Tutorial)

My problem is that inside my `index.html` (Take only this .html file as an example, but it is the same for all .html on my website) I have:

```
<script src="/Public/index.js"></script>
```

to include my .js file.

Folder tree of my project is the following:
[Folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rxMW.png)

With the script included in that way, no error arises, but when I sent the email, the webpage won't load and does not redirect to /send.

If I include the script in this way:

```
<script src="../index.js"></script>
```

It works fine and the website is redirected after the mail is sent, but it shows me this error:

> GET http://localhost:5000/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have read a lot of similar posts, where the problem was the incorrect use of `express.static`, and my opinion is that I made some mistakes with it, but I can't get what.

Inside my `server.js` I insert this code to use `express.static`:

```
app.use("/Public", express.static(process.cwd() + "/Public"));
```

and for route I use this:

```
app.route("/").get(function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(process.cwd() +"/Public/html/index.html");
});
```

Could someone help me to understand it?

This is the index.js code:

```
const form = document.getElementById("contact-form");
const formEvent = form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  let mail = new FormData(form);
  sendMail(mail);
});

const sendMail = (mail) => {
 fetch("/send", {
 method: "POST",
 body: mail,
}).then((response) => {
  return response.json;
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `express.static` middleware, you need to only specify the folder to serve static files from. No route is required when used, you can also use `path` to resolve the path:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('Public')));
```

The issue you've mentioned is because of the script URL, so when including your `index.js` using relative URL `../index.js` this works because it is relative to the currently loaded file `index.html` but up one folder.

```
<script src="../index.js"></script>
```

The issue in `/Public/index.js` is that `Public` folder is considered as the root for your static files. So in order to use absolute URL for script you shouldn't include 'Public' folder in your URL:

```
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

This should fix your issue and load your script correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
I've tried to use the relative path, as you suggested to me, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you @TKingu share the `index.js` script content? That will give us more details in order to help you

Comment: Did you try to use absolute URL like the second code `<script src="/index.js"></script>`? Do you get any response in `then()` after sending the email? Try to log the response

Comment: I was triyng to modify the path, but now it shows this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at index.js:1:1)`. 

I've added `console.log(response);` to my index.js inside the .then, but nothing appears, since when the response arrives it changes the page, as it should do since I have :

`res.status(200).sendFile(process.cwd() + "/Public/html/send.html");`

in my server.js at the transporter.sendMail function

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I was able to solve this problem using:
>
> ```
> <script type="javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Note that `type="javascript"` is not particularly complete and the `type` parameter in general for JavaScript script elements is no longer recommended for use in HTML5.